# Using JQuery to change CSS of element with dynamic class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to change the CSS of an element within a for-loop so that every element in the loop get different CSSes.

```
for(blablabla.. i++){
 icon: myIcon = L.divIcon({
       className: 'tempPanel s' + trackers[index].id
})}
```

This makes every element's class contain 'tempPanel' and 's1' or 's2' or 's3' and so on..
After that i have..

```
$('.s' + trackers[index].id).css("background-image", "url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,"+ app6aIcon +"')");
```

..because i want every element to have the CSS properties of both tempPanel and s*X*. This however doesnt give the objects a background image. If i change code to..

```
$('.tempPanel').css("background-image", "url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,"+ app6aIcon +"')");
```

.. all the elements will get the same background-image (obviously)..

How can i give elements different background and still apply CSS properties of tempPanel?

Comment: Please provide more information. Such questions will be ignored in SO

Comment: Such questions? Don't know how I can explain myself any better..

Comment: Do you think you can provide a sample code in http://jsfiddle.net/? That would be help you and the readers.

Comment: How many of the 's1', 's2' , 's3' ... classes will there be, infinite or a set maximum? And are they all contained in a div that acts as a wrapper or could you add one?

Comment: How is the first way different to the second? You're still adding the same bg image to either tempPanel or sX - am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks @DelightedD0D. Infinite s-classes in theory. They are contained in a div "leaflet-marker-pane". The names "s1,s2......" are just me trying to give every object that I recieve different classes. Every class' image is used as a marker in Leaflet.js.

Comment: is the image url stored in those objects?

Comment: @DelightedD0D With the second JQuery example, yes. With the first one, no. Darren Sweeney, thats basically the same thing I am asking :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what your use is but here is a contrived example of how to set the background image of each element with a particular class to a different image provided by some data source. I'm using data attributes on other html elements to store the image urls but you could use an array or an object ....whatever you want really.

Note that this method leaves out the second class altogether and instead uses `eq()` with the class we already have.

```js
$('.tempPanel').each(function() {
  var cur = $('.tempPanel').index($(this));
  var url = $('.holder').eq(cur).data('img-url');
  $(this).css('background-image', 'url(' + url + ')');

});
```

```css
.tempPanel {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="holder" data-img-url="https://placeimg.com/100/100/arch"></div>
<div class="holder" data-img-url="https://placeimg.com/100/100/nature"></div>
<div class="holder" data-img-url="https://placeimg.com/100/100/people"></div>

<br>

<div class="tempPanel"></div>
<div class="tempPanel"></div>
<div class="tempPanel"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for trying to help me, I really appriciate it. Got it solved now.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it now, and the answer is pretty simple. All I had to do was place the JQuery.css line *AFTER* the className was given to the element. I also changed className to className: 's'+index instead of 'tempPanel s' + index.

Thank you so much for answering.